# Python next iterator in a loop

Tags: python, iterator

I have a small routine like this:

```
to_use = [True] * n
val = 0
while (val is not None) :
   # various manipulations on val
   # so the val below is different from
   # val entering the loop
   to_use[val] = False
   val = next((i for i in range(n) if to_use[i]),None)
```

In my sample, `n` is of the order of a millon. Is the last like with the iterator the most efficient way to get the next "`val`"?. Or will it go through `to_use` from `0` each time in the loop? Note that once `to_use[i]=False`, its never reset to `True`.

Comment: You're simply cycling through every value in `to_use` in the last line, so you'll always get `val = 0` at the end of each loop. The only reason this terminates is because you set `to_use[0]` to `false`, so `next` gives you `None`. Seriously, try printing the value of `val` in each iteration.

Comment: It will go through `to_use` starting at 0 each time in the loop.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Please read the comment in his code.

Comment: No, it will be the smallest value of `i` such that `to_use[i]` is `False`.

Comment: @smarx You're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to smarx's comment after the question, I was able to solve this. The iterator will go through million entries in `to_use` everytime its called. Since I know that `to_use` entries do not change after being set to `False`, I wrote an explicit loop keeping track of where the previous loop left off, and started searching from there.

```
val = next((i for i in range(n) if to_use[i]),None)
```

cProfile shows 208 seconds for the whole code, most of which is from this line:

```
         900811 function calls in 208.227 seconds
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   199599  207.427    0.001  207.427    0.001 toposort.py:43(<genexpr>)
```

Explicit call

```
start = 0
to_use = [True] * n
val = 0
while (val is not None) :
   # various manipulations on val
   # so the val below is different from
   # val entering the loop
   to_use[val] = False
   val = None
   for i in range(start,n):
      if to_use[i]:
           val = i
           start = i
           break
```

cProfile shows 0.513 seconds for the whole code

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just going through the loop one item at a time and changing it from True to False:

In Python 2:

```
for i in xrange(len(to_use)):
    to_use[i] = False
```

In Python 3:

```
for i in range(len(to_use)):
    to_use[i] = False
```

xrange in Python 2 and range in Python 3 are iterators, so you they won't create a the list [0..len(n)].

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to make `to_use` a `set` of values instead:

```
to_use = set(range(n))

while len(to_use) > 0:
    val = min(to_use)
    # val manipulation here
    to_use.remove(val)
```

Note that this approach requires scanning through all the remaining values at each iteration. On average, per iteration, it scans through `n/2` values. Your original approach may be faster or slower than that depending on which elements of the list get set to `False` in which order. (If you tend to set things to `False` from the end of the list, your approach may already be faster. If you tend to set things to `False` from the beginning of the list, this `set` approach may be faster.)